# jQuery - Slide up div on textbox focus

Tags: jquery

At the moment I have:-

```
jQuery("#search-jobs").keyup(function() {

    if (!jQuery(this).val()) {
        jQuery('#search-controls').slideUp(300);
    } else {
        jQuery('#search-controls').slideDown(300);
    }

});
```

Which slides up the search-controls as soon as you start typing in a textbox. I want to change this so that when the textbox has focus, this slides up instead. I have tried:-

```
jQuery("#search-jobs").focus(function () {

    jQuery('#search-controls').slideUp(300);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="meta-content">
   <div id="search-controls" style="display: block;">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <select>
            <option value="All">All sectors</option>
            <option value="Finance">Finance</option>
            <option value="Hr">Human Resources</option>
            <option value="Procurement">Procurement &amp; Supply Chain</option>
            <option value="Sales">Sales &amp; Marketing</option>
         </select>
         <select>
            <option value="All">Salary range</option>
            <option value="10000">£10,000 - £19,999</option>
            <option value="20000">£20,000 - £29,999</option>
            <option value="30000">£30,000 - £49,999</option>
            <option value="50000">£50,000 - £69,999</option>
            <option value="70000">£70,000 - £99,999</option>
            <option value="100000">£100,000+</option>
            <option value=""></option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <select>
            <option value="All">All job types</option>
            <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
            <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
            <option value="Interim">Interim</option>
         </select>
         <select>
            <option value="All">All job locations</option>
            <option value="Leicester">Leicester</option>
            <option value="Nottingham">Nottingham</option>
            <option value="Derby">Derby</option>
            <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input id="search-jobs" type="text" placeholder="Search DISTINCT for jobs e.g. Accountant"><span class="icon-search"></span>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <a class="text-white" href="#">
      <p class="meta-text">I’m an employer looking for candidates<span class="more-info"></span></p>
   </a>
</div>
```

But this is not working, any ideas?

Comment: Post your html too, so we can exclude some direct questions

Comment: Are you wanting to slide it back down when it is no longer focused? You can do that like this https://jsfiddle.net/qpnfrrhf/

Comment: `.slideUp()` is the jquery method to hide something, not "slide it up"... If you want to show something you need `.slideDown()`, which will make it visible.

Comment: I think you've gotten the references of `up` and `down` mixed up.

Comment: Do you want it to hide when you are focusing no matter the value is empty or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a slideUp on focus and a slideDown on blur, you can do it like this :

```
jQuery("#search-jobs").focus(function() {
   jQuery('#search-controls').slideUp(300);
}).blur(function() {
   jQuery('#search-controls').slideDown(300);
});
```

And if you want a slideDown on focus and a slideUp on blur, you can do it like this :

```
jQuery("#search-jobs").focus(function() {
   jQuery('#search-controls').slideDown(300);
}).blur(function() {
   jQuery('#search-controls').slideUp(300);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed, just the other way around, so the slideUp is in the .blur function and vice versa

Comment: You're welcome @nsilva. Don't forget to accept the answer ; )